# Automatic META-INF/services generation in Scala and SBT for ServiceLoader

Tags: scala, sbt, annotation-processing, serviceloader

Is there a way, in Scala and SBT, to automatically generate `META-INF/services/*` resource files for later use by `java.util.ServiceLoader` by annotating classes, like [Google Auto Service](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service) does for Java projects?

i.e.

```
package foo.bar

import my.exported.ServiceInterface

@AutoService[ServiceInterface]
class MyService extends ServiceInterface{
  // …
}
```

to automatically generate the file `META-INF/services/my.exported.ServiceInterface` in the resources folder. The file will contain:

```
foo.bar.MyService
```

(I don't think I can use Google Auto Service directly, as it doesn't work with Scala classes -- see [this comment on a realm-java github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1531#issuecomment-150361774).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using https://github.com/nyavro/spi-plugin.

The approach used in this plugin differs from using annotations - it uses whole packages as a source of interfaces and applies to packages of interface implementations.